# Hide/Show a div on click problems

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a code where it should hide and show a div onclick of any tag. And this works but, it only works if I click the tag twice. After I click it twice then it will start showing and hiding on every click. How do I fix this?

Onclick

```
<span style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="ShowDIV();"><img src="pictures/view.png" /></span>
```

Javascript

```
function ShowDIV(){
if (DIV1.style.display=="none") DIV1.style.display="block";
else DIV1.style.display="none";
}
```

HTML Div CSS

```
div.popup
{
display:none;
background-image:url('pictures/opacitycover.png');
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Where's the code for DIV1? I'd bet that when you first initialize `ShowDIV()`, that `DIV1.style.display=="none"` is false, so it sets the display to 'none'.

Comment: Can you show your html that defines DIV1?

Comment: Instead of setting attributes, you should set different css flags for the div by adding and removing classes. Set the .show class first, then on click, if class is .show, remove class and add .hide

Comment: you don't really even need that....its just a div

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly...I'm honestly not sure why it does that though if the css is defined. Can you put that as an answer so I can count it as the answer?